# React native fs upload files issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am using https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs for upload files, but it's not sending any request to my server and sometimes it throws a socket-io issue, please check my current code that I have used.

I have tried simple fetch using form data but it works for ios only not in android

```
const toUrl =  'http://***';
const name = 'file_XCzY_SINGLE_FILE_POST';
const filename = 'IMG-20190514-WA0003.jpg';
const filepath = 'content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A209152';
const filetype = 'image/jpeg';


const params = {
  c2f: "HP4S",
  isIOS: false,
  meta_Chartfield_Number: '121212',
  meta_Comments: "",
  meta_Department: "%user_ldap_department%",
  meta_Due_date_Poster_Order_Form: null,
  meta_Due_time_Poster_Order_Form: "4 pm",
  meta_Email: "%user_ldap_mail%",
  meta_Name123: "%user_ldap_displayName%",
  name: "file_XCzY_SINGLE_FILE_POST",
  the_action: "STOR",
  uploadPath: "%2FTest%2F"
};


 const uploadBegin = (response) => {
   const jobId = response.jobId;
   console.log('UPLOAD HAS BEGUN! JobId: ' + jobId);
 };

 const uploadProgress = (response) => {
   const percentage = 
 Math.floor((response.totalBytesSent/response.totalBytesExpectedToSend) 
 * 100);
   console.log('UPLOAD IS ' + percentage + '% DONE!');
 };


 RNFS.uploadFiles({
   toUrl: encodeURI(url),
   files: [{
     name
     filename
     filepath
     filetype
   }],
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
     'Cookie': 'my-cookies*****'
   },
   fields: params,
   begin: uploadBegin,
   beginCallback: uploadBegin,
   progressCallback: uploadProgress,
   progress: uploadProgress
   }).promise.then((response) => {
    console.log(response,"<<< Response");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     console.log('FILES UPLOADED!');
    } else {
     console.log('SERVER ERROR');
    }
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     if (err.description) {
      switch (err.description) {
        case "cancelled":
         console.log("Upload cancelled");
         break;
        case "empty":
          console.log("Empty file");
        default:
          //Unknown
       }
      } else {
        //Weird
        console.log('Weird')
      }
       console.log(err);
    });
```

Please let me know if I did any mistakes in my code like fields, or anything else, it would be really helpful for me

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if the issue is with SSL encryption?

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: Looks like RNFS.uploadFiles does not support content://

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with the `uploadFile` in `react-native-fs`. Instead of this, I used `axios` by wrapping the content in the form data and passed to the server. (In my case, I need to upload/send zip file to a server).

I did something like this:

```js
const path = `${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/data.zip`;
const getFile = {
  uri: `file://${path}`,
  name: 'data.zip',
  type: 'application/zip',
};

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', getFileData);


axios
  .post(`API_URL`, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {})
  .catch(err => {});
```